# Helix Toolkit mirror X axis

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to mirror the entire x axis of a HelixViewport3D to match a coordinate system in another application.

I've tried using the Transform property on the camera like this:

```
<OrthographicCamera Position=".5,.5,2" LookDirection="0,0,-1.6" UpDirection="0,-2,0" >
    <OrthographicCamera.Transform>
        <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="-1"/>
    </OrthographicCamera.Transform>
</OrthographicCamera>
```

This produces no results that I can see. Is there another way to do this without changing the position values of the objects in my viewport?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the transform to the visual model instead of the camera:

```
    <ht:HelixViewport3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="-1"/>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            <ht:DefaultLights/>
            <ht:CubeVisual3D Center="5,0,0" Fill="Green"/>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </ht:HelixViewport3D>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip. There seems to be an issue when I use a negative scale with a PointsVisual3D. The points don't get rendered. Any idea why this might be?